# my_set.copy().add( something ) why return None

Tags: python

I want to create a new larger set based on a small set

Here is my code,

```
>>> a = {1, 2}
>>> b = a.copy().add(3)
>>> print(a)
{1, 2}
>>> print(b)
None
```

I thought it in a Java-like way,

I assume a.copy() return a set object, so I can call its methods by "."

Why it gets None in Python? Which concept in Python should I learn?

I know I can fix it by change it to

```
>>> a = {1, 2}
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> b.add(3)
```